# display random images from folder

Tags: actionscript-3

What should I use too pick random images from a folder and display it on the sage?
I know I will neeed:
1. Math.random thingy - to roll random numbers
2. XML file - which I don't know how to incorporate int the flash file
3. a folder with pictures, which I already have
Any ideas what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.To placed image, fla as follows.

[image]

2.Try the following. below code is just a skeleton. you try more extended.

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;

var imgRequest:URLRequest;
var randCount:int = 6*Math.random();
function loadImage():void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i<randCount; i++)
    {
        var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        imgRequest = new URLRequest();
        imgRequest.url = "img/img" + int(6*Math.random()) +".jpg";
        trace(imgRequest.url);
        imgLoader.load(imgRequest);
        imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, unloadedImg);
        imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedImg);
    }
}

function onLoadedImg(e:Event):void
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedImg);

    var bmp:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content;

    bmp.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    bmp.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    bmp.width = 200;
    bmp.height = 200;
    this.addChild(bmp);
}

function unloadedImg(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, unloadedImg);
    trace("load Failed:" + e);
}

loadImage();
```

Comment: THANKS BRO! I will give it a try this weekend! I would vote you up, but the system won't allow me until my rep's up a bit more  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an array of the images and then make the math random;

```
var selected:Array=[];//new array

while (selected.length<4) {

    //myArray is the array with your pictures.
    var si:int=Math.floor(Math.random()*_myArray.length);

    if (selected.indexOf(si)==-1) selected.push(si);
}

trace(_myArray[selected[0]]); // first selected flag
trace(_myArray[selected[3]]); // fourth selected flag
```